# [T1]{fontenc}, [utf8]{inputenc} and {microtype}: Kerning does not work

Tags: fonts, unicode, font-encodings, kerning

My code looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\begin{document}
    \section{AVAW Wo}
    AVAW Wo
\end{document}
```

I don’t know what is wrong. I have set the option `kerning=true` – and it still does not work.

[image]

Comment: Remove the calls to ae and aecompl

Comment: If I do that, nothing will change. The font will just turn into an ugly bitmap font – and that’s it.

Comment: Then install the cm-super package.

Comment: @Nemgathos Are you running MiKTeX, by chance?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't work"? -- there is kerning in your example (with or without `microtype`); I also guess there's a misunderstanding about the `kerning` option, check the `microtype` manual

Comment: Installing the `cm-super` package did not work. And I am running MiKTeX. Furthermore, there does not seem to be any kerning in my example because it stays the same if I set `kerning=false`.

Comment: I can only repeat myself: (1) there _is_ kerning in your example (add `\tracingoutput1 \showboxdepth100 \showboxbreadth100` to your example, and you will see the `\kern` directives in the log file). (2) the `kerning` option of `microtype` does not affect normal kerning, which is built into the font.

Comment: @Robert I have also posted two examples below Mico’s answer ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1N9Y.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naLlc.png)). If that is proper krening, I have to manually adjust some properties of the kerning table.

Comment: If you still get bitmaps after installing cm-super, run on a command line `updmap`. But don't use ae and aecompl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a solution that works for me! [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) gave me a good hint in a comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408034/149141).

My preamble now looks as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=false,kerning=true,spacing=false,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}
```

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I would like to question your claim that the `kerning` option of the `microtype` package "doesn't work". Specifically, compare the following two screenshots: the upper was compiled with pdfLaTeX, and the lower was compiled with LuaLaTeX. (Recall that the `kerning` and `spacing` options currently aren't enabled under LuaLaTeX.)  (Aside: I use MacTeX2017, on a MacBook Pro that runs MacOS X 10.13.2 "High Sierra".) To my eye at least, microtype does apply additional kerning under pdfLaTeX.

[image]

[image]

(The framelines are produced by the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package.)

Comment: I can understand that this example might not be that good. But what do you think about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1N9Y.png)? I have even had something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naLlc.png).