# Manually suppressing ligatures with {} does not work throughout the document

Tags: fonts, microtype, ligatures

I have decided to write a document **without** using `microtype` because [I have not yet figured out how to solve my kerning issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407821/t1fontenc-utf8inputenc-and-microtype-kerning-does-not-work). But when I am not using microtype, I also cannot use `\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = * }`.

Thus, I have tried to suppress ligatures manually. For example, I write `f{}ind` instead of `find`, etc.

Sometimes, this works, but sometimes it does not. I wonder why that is.

I have compiled my document several times and started my PDF-viewer from anew again and again – and I still see these nasty ligatures every now and then.

**Edit:** My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,T3,T4]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ae,aecompl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[bottom,hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\clubpenalty10000
\widowpenalty10000
\displaywidowpenalty=10000
\zmakeperpage{footnote}
% Remove counter "footnote" from the reset counter list
% of counter "chapter".
\usepackage{remreset}
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\geometry{
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    bindingoffset=0mm
}
\begin{document}
    \chapter*{Einleitung}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Einleitung} {}
    of{}fen

    Footnote\footnote{text}

    of{}fen

    Doch häuf{}ig \dots\\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: if you are using pdftex `{}` works in some cases and not in others,  if using luatex it never works, `\/` or `\mbox{}` will work in all cases

Comment: `\mbox{}` works pretty good! `\/`, however, produces some white space between `f` and `i` in my example.

Comment: Do you *really* need T4 as the last specified encoding, which makes it the default one? Besides, I think to already have told you that `ae` and `aecompl` are obsolete.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example.

Comment: `\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = * }` is not a good idea anyway -- it switches of kerning too, see the documentation. But you can use `\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}` to disable f-ligatures (but you are the first claiming that they are ugly, and disabling them and not using microtype will not make your document look more professional).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This has finally solved my problems! No ligatures, Computer Modern Roman as a vector font with kerning (although I think that adjusting the kerning manually would be a good thing because it is not very good at every kerning pair in my opinion).

Answer (score 3):

Use `xelatex` or `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}    
find

\addfontfeatures{Ligatures=NoCommon}
find
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the first "find" is nice, and the second "find" is ugly :)